# NSURLResponse does not have a member named allHeaderFields

Tags: ios, post, http-headers, swift, nsurlrequest

I'm making a POST request to an API and I get the response successfully in Swift. Below is my code.

```
private func getData(url: NSURL) {
    let config: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error {
            println("Error Occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            println("\(response.allHeaderFields)") // Error
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

I'm trying to dump the header fields using `allHeaderFields` but I get an error saying **NSURLResponse does not have a member named allHeaderFields**. But it *[does](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields)* have it!

There must be something wrong with the syntax or the way I'm calling it. Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elaborating on what Yogesh said...!

Try to cast the NSURLRespones into a NSHTTPURLResponse using "as", because I'm betting the NSURLResponse is actually a NSHTTPURLResponse, or I'm betting that is possible.

Here is what I mean:

```
private func getData(url: NSURL) {
    let config: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, urlResponse: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if let httpUrlResponse = urlResponse as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        {
            if error {
                println("Error Occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                println("\(httpUrlResponse.allHeaderFields)") // Error
            }
        }
        })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the link you have provided [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields)

> The NSHTTPURLResponse class is a subclass of NSURLResponse that provides methods for accessing information specific to HTTP protocol responses

And `allHeaderFields` is method of `NSHTTPURLResponse` class not `NSURLResponse` class. So you have to use `NSHTTPURLResponse` instead of `NSURLResponse` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
if navigationResponse.response is HTTPURLResponse {
      let response = navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse
      print(response.allHeaderFields) // all headers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3 and higher solution

Here is a solution to handle the data tasks in Swift 3 and higher.

```
let urlPath: String = "http://www.google.de"
guard let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath) else { return }
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let response: URLResponse?

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }       
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    }
}.resume()
```